# Chrome Missing history option in settings

Tags: google-chrome

I have been using google chrome but i just realized today that when I go to "setting" so as to refer to my browsing history, the history button/ hyperlink is not there. I only have "Extensions", "settings" and "about". The "history" option is not there yet it used to be there. Which settings do I need to modify to have it back?
Thanks,

Comment: Does 'chrome://history' in the URL bar still work?  If so settings>advanced>clear history

Comment: Thanks Linuxdev2013, it did the trick. I didnt think of "chrome://history"